# FIRST_ROWS syntax

Tags: oracle, hint

Recently, I observed a usage of FIRST_ROWS hint written as `FIRST_ROWS EXPMA 851.120.01`
I know the general syntax of FIRST_ROWS hint which should have a (n) value which means the number of rows to be ordered.

Can anyone tell me if the syntax `FIRST_ROWS EXPMA 851.120.01` is correct and what might be the meaning of "EXPMA" and "851.120.01"?

Thank you,

Comment: Where did you see this usage? Did it compile and work? From I can find from [the official Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements006.htm#BABGCCFG), this is incorrect syntax.

Comment: Hints are a subset of comments, so if you don't specify the hint syntax correctly, it'll just be treated as a comment. I'm assuming this code works fine, but the FIRST_ROWS hint does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle allows junk in hints, because the syntax is part of SQL commenting. I sometimes wish ignored hint text would get highlighted in the notes section of execution plans, but it's silently ignored.

Possibly some developer was experimenting and wanted to differentiate between SQL IDs in v$sql.